# Can I, perhaps with Cydia, on my iPhone, with out using iTunes, back up an app before updating to the newest version?

Tags: applications, ios

There is an app that I currently have that I like, an update is available, but I haven't updated the app because while the new version adds some features I like, it also removes some features.  I would like to run both versions on my iPhone, so that I can use the old version when I want the removed feature, and run the new version when I don't.  Can I, Clone an App to a new name/directory on my iPhone, and then run the update, leaving me with two icons on my home screen, one that launches the old version, and one that launches the new version?

Comment: I just got done writing a tutorial on how to do this, but when I got to the end, I realized that it didn't work. I found a different way to do it that should work, though, so I'm going to test it out and then return here to post my findings.

Comment: @Andrew Larsson - any progress?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I'll put a note down for me to figure this out, and hopefully I'll have an answer by tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry it's been taking me so long. I've been quite busy these past few weeks. I'll get around to this as soon as I can.